# iOS - UITableView Position Resets When Controller is Presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios8

So I have a view controller that has a `UITableView` that covers the bottom half of the controller.  I have a button in the top section header that allows the user to minimize or maximize the `UITableView`.  When the button is pressed the y component  of the `UITableView`'s position is modified so that the `UITableView` appears to have minimized to the bottom of the screen.  When the button is pressed while the `UITableView` is in its minimized state the `UIableView`'s y position is returned to its original value. Both the maximizing and minimizing of the `UITableView` are animated to provide a smooth transition between the opened and closed states of the `UITableView`.

This all works very nicely and provides a user experience that allows the user to utilize the information displayed in the table view and the information displayed within the view controller behind it.  The problem comes when a second controller is presented over top.  For some reason when the user dismisses the second controller the table view always returns to its initial position regardless of the position it was in at the time the second controller was presented.  This creates many issues as the initial view controller still thinks the table view is in the position it was at the time of presentation.  Why is this? Why are the positions of components reset when a view controller is presented over top and then dismissed?

Here is how I defined my `UITableView` as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *reviewTable;
```

Here is how I minimize/maximize my table view:

```
- (IBAction)btnExpandCompress:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *downImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowDown.png"];
    UIImage *upImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowUp.png"];
    UIButton *btnExpandCompress = (UIButton *)sender;
    [btnExpandCompress setEnabled:NO];

    //global flag to tell if the table view is maximized or minimized
    if (showingReviews)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = reviewTable.frame;
            frame.origin.y += reviewTable.frame.size.height - 30;
            reviewTable.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            showingReviews = NO;
            [btnExpandCompress setEnabled:YES];
            [btnExpandCompress setBackgroundImage:upImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = reviewTable.frame;
            frame.origin.y -= reviewTable.frame.size.height - 30;
            reviewTable.frame = frame;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            showingReviews = YES;
            [btnExpandCompress setEnabled:YES];
            [btnExpandCompress setBackgroundImage:downImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }];
    }
}
```

If there is any other information needed to answer this question please let me know.

Comment: every think works fine with the above code i think did u override `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` in the veiewcontroller contains tableview .. ?

Comment: I did not override either of those methods.  Is there anything else that it could be? @Shan

Comment: i tired with your situation, it works fine hear there is no shifting of tableview to initial position even after the dismiss of the second controller i think u are setting some where to initial position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the reason that the UITableView was returning to its original position was because of issues regarding auto layout.  When I disabled auto layout in the storyboard file the UITableView behaved correctly.  This caused a number of other issues in my application's UI so I settled on disabling auto layout for just the UITableView in question.  This worked, and here is the code I used to do it:

```
//This disables autolayout for myTableView
myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

Feel free to comment if there are any issues with my solution that I have overlooked.  If not I will accept this answer as it seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment, I'll have to add this as an answer.

Open your *`storyboard->View Controller(Which has the table view)-> View`* of the View controller.

> Inside this view, if the tableView is first in the view hierarchy from
>   the top, the table view cells shift downwards to the height of the
>   navigation bar.

Hope this helps!